# Synchronize the files from One folder of a Server to other

Tags: scripting, rhel, rsync, synchronization

I need a script in which Files of One server will be copied to other folder of another server ONLY AND ONLY IF the file on SOURCE SERVER file doesn't exist on DESTINATION SERVER.

## Further Detail

This will be running all time on a SOURCE server if the user create the FILE on SOURCE SERVER and when the file is completed and saved it(the Command or script) first check on DESTINATION SERVER if the file exist on DEST. SERVER if not then copy if to DEST. SERVER

How to do that I have no idea of scripting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `rsync`'s `--ignore-existing` flag. From `man rsync`:

```
--ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on receiver
```

To do this between two distinct servers you'd do something like this:

```
rsync --ignore-existing -avz -e ssh source remoteuser@remoteserver:destination
```

If you are truly going to be running this "all the time" (ie. continuously) like you say in the question, I'd highly recommend using an `inotify` based solution instead, which would eliminate a lot of overhead.

Comment: Please correct if im wrong **rsync --ignore-existing -avz -e ssh *source* remoteuser@remoteserver:destination** shouldn't the source comes BEFORE the ssh.

Comment: @UmairMustafa - No, ssh is an argument to `rsync` (specifically its the option for the `-e` parameter being passed) which specifies the program to be used to acquire the remote shell. Take a look at `man rsync`.

Comment: In most cases the `-e ssh` can actually be omitted, as it will default to that.

Comment: @jordanm Is that undocumented? I can't see that in the manual anywhere... if it is undocumented I *really* would not recommend omitting it, especially in a script.

Comment: It's not really spelled out, but the documentation does explain `user@host:/foo` will use a remote shell and `user@host::/foo` will attempt to connect to an rsync daemon. I have only used `-e` when needing to pass extra options to `ssh` such as `-i`.

Comment: Close to solving the issue. 1: I run this command and it works but it does ask for remote server password coz of ssh parameter How to make it not ask for password for Remote server it should only ask ONCE because it will running continously. 2: Secondly Can the same command be used to synchronize Folder instead of Files. BTW great help

Comment: Run it with a limited account, run `ssh-agent`, run `ssh-add` to add the key, put the `ssh-agent` environment variables in the environment that this script will run in. Done.

Answer (score 1):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html) is another such tool that does not have the same feature set as rsync, but might be just as well suited for this partifular case.

There is a nice [howto](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unison-file-synchronizer-tool/) which also explains how to integrate with [inotify](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/)